# Bouncing of curved surface

Tags: java, android

I am making a game where I have a ball bouncing inside a circular ring.
I understand that when the ball hits a wall, it will treat it as a flat wall and will bounce off at an angle from the normal. But, I can't figure out how to find that angle and make appropriate changes to xVelocity and yVelocity.

This is what I have so far:

```
        left = ball.getBounds().left;
        right = ball.getBounds().right;
        top = ball.getBounds().top;
        bottom = ball.getBounds().bottom;

        left+=vX;
        right+=vX;
        top+=vY;
        bottom+=vY;
        ball.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        invalidate();

        int relativeX = left - ring.getCenterX() + RADIUS;
        int relativeY = top - ring.getCenterY() + RADIUS;
        int relativeRadius = ring.getRadius() - deviceWidth/16 - RADIUS;

        if(Math.pow(relativeX,2)+Math.pow(relativeY,2) >= Math.pow(relativeRadius ,2) && check) {
            if(Math.abs(relativeX) > Math.abs(relativeY)) {
                vX*=-1;
            }
            if(Math.abs(relativeX) < Math.abs(relativeY)) {
                vY*=-1;
            }
            if(Math.abs(relativeX) == Math.abs(relativeY)) {
                vX*=-1;
                vY*=-1;
            }
        }
```

I use Pythagoras theorem to find the point where the ball collides with the inner surface of the circle (ring). But I know that the code I am currently using to bounce the ball is wrong and I can't figure out what the right way would be.

Comment: It's usually done using the unit normal vector to the surface of the wall and the velocity vector of the ball.  You want to reverse the sign of the ball velocity component normal to the wall and leave the tangential components unchanged.  It's a hard problem if you don't understand vectors or physics.

Comment: Since this is not really a Java question, but rather an algorithm question, you might get faster results asking in [algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)